# How to redirect my old blog domain to the new one?

Tags: blogger

I'm new here. I want to ask something. 
How to redirect my old blog domain to the new one?
Example :
I have blog with domain abc.blogspot.com. 
Then i changed it to abcd.blogspot.com. 
When someone visit abc.blogspot.com it will be redirect to abcd.blogspot.com or if someone visit abc.blogspot.com/a.html it will be redirect to abcd.blogspot.com/a.html. 
How to do that? Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

No, Blogger (which is the web-application used to build blogspot.com blogs) does not provide a re-direction option.

You can delete all the posts from abc.blogspot.com, and then make one post which says "Thanks for visiting, please go to abcd.blogspot.com".     Set up a custom redirect (Settings / Search) which sends all visitors to that post.